# Ratchet without Symfony session

Tags: session, websocket, session-cookies, ratchet

I want to work with ratchet without `Symfony` session and handle session with `php` handler between my web application and ratchet. but it doesn't work.

My code for session handling:

Run server : session.php`

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'memcached' );
ini_set('session.save_path', 'localhost:11211' );

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    require __DIR__ . './../src/MyApp/Chat.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
    new WsServer(
    new Chat()
    )
    , 8080
);

    $server->run();
```

My app: chat.php

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        session_start();

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
        $conn->send('Hello ' . session_id());
```

Client side :

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'memcached' );
ini_set('session.save_path', 'localhost:11211' );

session_start();

require __DIR__ . './../server/vendor/autoload.php';

$_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name'];

if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    var_dump($_SESSION['name']);
} else {
    echo 'Not set!!!';
}
```

My url for request :   `localhost/myfile/?name=shahrokh`

Answer (score 1):

This won't work. From the [Ratchet doc](http://socketo.me/docs/sessions):

> In order to access your session data in Ratchet, you must also use the
>   same Symfony Session Handler on you website.

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183917/starting-a-session-within-a-ratchet-websocket-connection AFAIK you have to start the session from a symfony view to access it in ratchet, even if you are using the symfony session handler.