# New to nodejs. what is the equivalent of PHP's session_start() in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, session

I would like to generate a session id, but have it unique to the browser, not per tab.

All I am able to find is this type of stuff >>

http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions

which demonstrates how to use sessions to store data, but it is limited in each tab ends up with a new session.  what I am looking for, is that the browser gets a unique session id which is generated automatically and accessible from other tabs.  trying to stay away from browser storage for now until it is has matured to the point that most users have that feature.  since we still have quite a number of users using older browsers that do not support local storage, a random session id is ideal.

I am using this unique id as the private 'room' which users of a chat program will join for support.  Each user would be in their own private room, but can access that same room across tabs. I know it's a bit sloppy, but from a beginner in nodejs's perspective it is much simpler to use some unique key to that browsers instance than to deal with cross-tab socket open/close detection, etc.  I realize using this method, each tab will have it's own socket connection to the server which I am ok with -- for now.

I have tried the following (which looks to me like it would use the sockets session, and not a browser session even if it did work), which doesn't work (probably obvious to someone experienced why this doesn't work.

Client

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.emit('set room', this.socket.sessionid);
})
```

Server

```
socket.on('set room', function(room) {
    socket.join(room);
    console.log('joined : ' + room);
});
```

Here is a simple script example, and whats happening using the answer provided to use `express-sessions`.  It isn't playing well with socket.io, or something is gone terribly wrong:

(removed the `app.use(function.....)` for session since it was causing the client to never reach the socket connection.

---

app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    session = require('express-session');

var settings = require('./settings.json');

server.listen(settings.port);

app.use(session({
    secret: settings.secret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

//app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//  var sess = req.session;
//  if(!sess.id) {
//      sess.id = sess.sessionID;
//  }
//});

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    validateHost('index.html', request, response);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){


    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        //io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
        console.log(session.sessionID);
        io.sockets.emit('new message', 'session:' + session.sessionID);
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('new message', data);
    });

    socket.on('set room', function(room) {
        socket.join(room);
        console.log('joined : ' + room);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });

});

function validateHost(file, request, response) {
    var hostname = ( request.headers.host.match(/:/g) ) ? request.headers.host.slice( 0, request.headers.host.indexOf(":") ) : request.headers.host;
//  var file = 'index.html';

    if(settings.hosts.indexOf(hostname)) {
        response.sendFile(__dirname + '/' + file);
    } else {
        response.statusCode = 404;
        response.write('Access Denied to ' + request.headers.host + ' ' + file);
        response.end();
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Realtime Private Chat</title>
    <style>
        #chat { height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; }
        #chat p { width: 270px; }

        .commentArea {
            font: 14px Arial;
            padding: 0 10px;
            margin-top: 20px;    
        }

        .bubbledLeft,.bubbledRight {
            margin-top: 20px;
            padding: 5px 9px;
            max-width: 50%;
            clear: both;
            position: relative;
        }

        .bubbledLeft{
            float: left;
            margin-right: auto;
            -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 0px;
            -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 0px;
            -o-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 0px;
            -ms-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 0px;
            border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 0px;
            background-color: #65B045;
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .bubbledLeft:before {
            border-bottom: 10px solid #65B045;
            border-left: 9px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: -8px;
            content: "";
        }

        .bubbledRight{
            float: right;
            margin-left: auto;
            text-align: right;
            -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 8px;
            -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 8px;
            -o-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 8px;
            -ms-border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 8px;
            border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 8px;
            background-color: #07D;
            color: white;
        }

        .bubbledRight:before {
            border-bottom: 9px solid #07D;
            border-right: 9px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: -8px;
            content: "";
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chat"></div>

    <form id="send-message">
        <input id="message" type="text" />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        var socket = io.connect();
        var sendmessage = $('#send-message');
        var sendmessagetext = $('#message');
        var chat = $('#chat');

        sendmessage.submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('send message', sendmessagetext.val());
            chat.append('<div class="bubbledRight">' + sendmessagetext.val() + '</div>');
            sendmessagetext.val('');
        })

        socket.on('connect', function() {
            //socket.emit('set room', this.socket.sessionid);
        })

        socket.on('new message', function(data) {
            chat.append('<div class="bubbledLeft">' + data + '</div>');
            chat.scrollTop(chat[0].scrollHeight)
//          console.log(data);
        });

    });

</script>

</html>
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "livechat",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Realtime Private Chat Server",
    "main": "app.js",
    "private": "true",
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies":{
        "socket.io":"1.3.5",
        "mysql":"2.8.0",
        "express":"4.13.1",
        "express-session":"1.11.3"
    }
}
```

settings.json

```
{
    "port":"3000",
    "hosts":[
            "127.0.0.1",
            "example.com"
        ],
    "secret":"faskjhfuwjhfjas"
}
```

When trying to read the session anywhere in socket, i get 'undefined'.

Comment: *"trying to stay away from browser storage for now until it is has matured to the point that most users have that feature"* such as cookies? pretty sure php uses cookies to store it's session id and persist across tabs...

Comment: The blog you linked to: http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions, shows exactly how to give the browser a session id that is available to all tabs. No, it doesn't store data in the browser. It stores data in RAM (and later you're shown how to store that data in Redis and MongoDB) and associates the session-id to that data automagically. You can, if you want, see the session-id but that blog post didn't demonstrate that.

Comment: @slebetman --  kinda need the session id.   don't care about storing odds/ends into the browser session.

Comment: You should use [`express-socket.io-session`](https://github.com/oskosk/express-socket.io-session).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be using a new implementation of the express-session and socket.io, one that marries the two together well! https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session

**Package.JSON**

Add dependencies

```
"socket.io" : "*",
"express-session" : "*",
"express-socket.io-session" : "*"
```

**App.js**

Add additional coding for session data

```
var server  = require("http").createServer(app),
    io = require("socket.io")(server),
    session = require("express-session")({
    secret: "my-secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  }),
  sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");


// Attach session
app.use(session);

// Share session with io sockets

io.use(sharedsession(session));

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    // Accept a login event with user's data
        console.log(session.id);
    socket.on("login", function(userdata) {
        socket.handshake.session.userdata = userdata;
    });
    socket.on("logout", function(userdata) {
        if (socket.handshake.session.userdata) {
            delete socket.handshake.session.userdata;
        }
    });        
});
```

Comment: sorry for the delayed response.   trying to play with this and not sure why but seems overly complex when all i need is the session id --  it's not playing well with socket.io either.

Comment: Does this git example help? https://github.com/adelura/socket.io-express-solution

Comment: I added the source I wrote for this, so you can see what I am trying to do, and where it is failing easier.  If it was just writing a session / cookie variable, it's not as big a deal as just getting the darn unique session id.   even trying to store it....  epic fail everywhere.  can't get the id, which is trivial in php.

Comment: gonna try and rework my code using that example -- hard to say until implementation if it helped or not -- logically, seems pretty straight forward....

Comment: @SanuelJackson apparently, sharing a session between HTTP and WebSockets (which is what you're basically trying to do) [isn't that trivial in PHP either](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25614651/893780).

Comment: I can write a socket server from scratch in PHP and handle sessions as part of the protocol.  You know, the 'http' protocol, that 'sends' data to the client,   sessions are a part of that -- same with cookies etc --  so what you are basically saying is that 'http' in nodejs doesn't have any support for sessions, cookies, etc....   is that correct ?

Comment: also, the recent demo you sent to me, claims to use it under io.use --- no idea how to translate into .on(<event>)  ....

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the link. Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session. What I noticed is the GIT link above is for an older version. I'm assuming they implemented a promise to the later version. I'm playing with your program to see if I can get it implemented. This NPM package may be of assistance and provide what you need easier. I'll work up an example shortly, in the meantime let me know your progress after seeing the link.

Comment: Updated with some additional code. Please let me know how this works out for you. If this does not work, are you interested in pushing code into a git repository so I can run exactly, or close to, what you have? We can work on this in Cloud9 and get your problem resolved in no time!

Comment: npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session  actually helped out quite a bit.   was able to hybrid that code into my server and it is working quite well.   thank you.

Comment: Good luck and I hope the rest goes smooth!